# LINQ - query table with related data

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a "Product" table that has related "Tegs"

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Tegs = new List<Teg>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Teg> Tegs { get; set; }
    public  virtual ICollection<Product> RelatedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Tegs:

```
public class Teg
{
     public Teg()
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TegName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

}

Given a product ID, using LINQ I would like to retrieve all products that have at least one teg as the selected product.

I am using this code:

```
Product product = db.Product.Include(u => u.Tegs).Where(u => u.Id == id).Single();
List<int> tegid = product.Tegs.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
IEnumerable<Product> relatedProducts = db.Product.Include(u => u.Tegs).Where(p => p.Tegs.Any(t => tegid.Contains(t.Id)));
```

Question 1:
How can I exclude from the relatedProducts the product with the ID?

Question 2: 
How can nest my List inside the Linq query for the relatedProducts ?

Answer (score 0):

On your first question, if I understand correctly, you want to exclude the product with the given productId from relatedProducts result list. In this case you just need to add one more condition to your Where() clause like this:

```
IEnumerable<Product> relatedProducts = db.Product
                  .Include(u => u.Tegs)
                  .Where(p => p.Tegs.Any(t => tegid.Contains(t.Id)) && p.Id != id);
```

And about your second question, I'm not quite sure what's the point here. Maybe you've meant to combine the second and third query in a single roundtrip to db?